# How to setup firewall on ubuntu for digital ocean?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, firewall, digital-ocean, ufw

In order to deploy a react app, I had to setup Nginx on Ubuntu and for Nginx I had to setup firewall. But when I ran command `sudo ufw app list`
It gives me list

```
Available applications:
  Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS
  OpenSSH
```

Now I have to allow HTTP for Nginx, I have to run command

```
 sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'
```

Which displays result like

```
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
```

Now to check status of firewall, we run command

```
 sudo ufw status
```

which returns

```
Status: inactive
```

I tried

```
sudo ufw default allow
```

But it doesn't work. So please help with solution

Answer (score 4):

Finally I worked it with command

```
sudo ufw enable
```

which prompts me with

```
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)?
```

I replied with y and then got result

```
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
```

Now when I check

```
sudo ufw status
```

It returns

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```